# Codeigniter 3 if statement not working correctly

Tags: codeigniter-3

Can anybody explain me this?

Because i think the if condition is easy and clear. I set `'userRole'` to show Admin Panel only if it is == 4.

If not than show me and teach me.

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('userLoggedIn')) { ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-link text-white"><?= $this->session->userdata('userName')." ".$this->session->userdata('userSurname'); ?></a>
            </li>

            <?php
                if ($this->session->userdata('userRole') == 4); {
                    echo "<li class='nav-item'>";
                    echo "<a href='' class='btn btn-link text-danger'>Admin Panel</a>";
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            ?>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="<?= base_url('auth/logout'); ?>" class="btn btn-link text-white">Odhlásiť</a>
            </li>
    <?php } else {?>
```

[image]

Comment: So what's wrong???

Comment: It should display Admin Panel only if `userRole` is 4 not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semi-colon after the second if statement just remove it and move on!

replace this

```
   <?php
        if ($this->session->userdata('userRole') == 4); {
        echo "<li class='nav-item'>";
        echo "<a href='' class='btn btn-link text-danger'>Admin Panel</a>";
        echo "</li>";
       }
   ?>
```

With this

```
   <?php
        if ($this->session->userdata('userRole') == 4) {
        echo "<li class='nav-item'>";
        echo "<a href='' class='btn btn-link text-danger'>Admin Panel</a>";
        echo "</li>";
       }
   ?>
```